# how to do set a AnimationTransition?

Tags: objective-c, transition

I want to set a Animation Transition like this

there is a link to open a website with safari in an app called newapp, when you clicked the link, this app will close and the safari will launch, I need the animation style for switching  two view, so can you tell me how? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Safari to open a site from newapp, that's an entirely different application from newapp and you don't get to instruct the O.S. how you want to do the transition.  The O.S. has it's default transition and there's no way to set or modify that.

This would be entirely different if you had a web view embedded into newapp... then you could control the transition.

Comment: thanks a lot,but what i want is that i want to do the transition like that.